# Custom UILabel setter

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

**Why doesn't change uilabel?**

I created some class, but can't override the setter

Code of .h file

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    UILabel * _lblName;
}
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel * lblName;

@end
```

Code of .m file

```
@synthesize lblName = _lblName;
```

```
- (void)setLblName:(UILabel *)lblName{
if(![_lblName isEqual:lblName]){
[_lblName release];
_lblName = [lblName retain];}}
```

```
- (IBAction)didCustomBtnClick:(id)sender {
UILabel* lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 100.0, 30.0)];
lbl.text = @"Duck";
self.lblName = lbl;
[lbl release];}
```

Comment: You probably shouldn't be synthesizing, having a custom ivar, and a custom setter all at once. It's not the problem here, its just a matter of style and keeping code as clean as possible.

Comment: And to clarify - the problem isn't with your property - IBOutlets are a one time hook-up, and any other objects allocated must manually be added to the view stack.